# How to downgrade to a lower version of jquery in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to downgrade from jquery 1.9 to 1.8, how can I do this in rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step-By-Step:

- Visit the jquery-rails project at http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails
- Navigate to the [Source Code](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) repository
- Open [VERSIONS.md](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md) from project structure
- Find the jQuery version you need (1.8) in jQuery column
- Find the gem version in the first column - 2.1.0 This is the version of jquery-rails that you need.
- Open the Gemfile from your project.
- Replace your jquery gem (`jquery-rails`) with

  ```
  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.0'
  ```
- Run `bundle install` and restart your rails server.